# Google Cloud Messaging service does not work properly. Unable to view or upload new APNS certificates

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, certificate

Today I found that iOS application doesn't receive push notifications (we use Google Cloud Messaging service). I tried to check the expiration date of certificates uploaded to GCM and found a strange bug with GCM [configuration page](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add). I unable to upload new certificate

[image]

Is there any alternative way to check uploaded certificates?

Comment: Found a reported bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64492589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the issue to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), because now GCM is a part of Firebase. And got an answer from Firebase support team that I have to [migrate my GCM project to Firebase console](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm#import_your_gcm_project_as_a_firebase_project). Doing so will not affect my existing configuration or I don't need to migrate SDK to FCM. It just got an ability to work with project via Firebase console.
How to find certificates in Firebase console see on screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
By the way there is information appeared at [Cloud Messaging page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm)
[image]